# Frameworks used for Objective-C and Objective-C++

Tags: iphone, frameworks, objective-c++

Are the frameworks used for Objective-C programming common for Objective-C++ in iPhone programming?like Core foundation , UIKit etc..

Answer (score 1):

yes - apple doesn't supply many c++ interfaces so... you're working primarily with their c and objc libraries for many tasks. of course, you also have the option to integrate stl and many other c++ libs where you desire.